# Can i upgrade ubuntu without losing my apps and files?

Tags: upgrade

I was just wondering since i have the 12.04 lts ubuntu edition if it's possible to upgrade it to 13.04 or even 14.04 after it gets released without losing any of my files and installed apps?

That's actually the main reason i chose the LTS version because i didn't know if i had to re-install all my apps every time a new ubuntu version gets released.

Comment: possible duplicated http://askubuntu.com/questions/37063/will-everything-downloaded-fonts-files-apps-etc-remains-the-same-when-i-upgr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. However, the restriction is the versions you can upgrade to.

Ubuntu's versioning scheme is that 12.04 and 14.04 are LTS releases and are supported for a longer period of time than non-LTS releases, which are the releases inbetween (12.10, 13.04, 13.10). Due to support length changes before 13.04 was released, the current supported non-LTS releases are 12.10 and 13.10 (13.04 has reached End-Of-Life).

As for upgrading, you cannot directly upgrade from 12.04 (LTS) to 13.04 (non-LTS) (nor can you upgrade to 13.04 in any way, since it is EOL); You will have to go through 12.10, and then jump to 13.10. Usually, for non-LTS releases, you have to go through each version inbetween.

However, you will be able to upgrade directly from 12.04 (LTS) to 14.04 (LTS) when 14.04 is released.

Comment: Thanks. Just another question. Will the programs i have installed like R with adding a respositοry manualy which was the precise pancolin package(12.04) in that case work after a possible upgrade or would i have to add a new respository ?

Comment: Unless there are dependency conflicts (which hasn't been the case), those programs won't be removed, but the PPA will be disabled during and after the upgrade. You'll need to manually re-enable the PPA and update the distro (change precise to trusty).

Comment: Edit: my comment should say "(which hasn't been the case for me)"

Comment: Wait, already? To 13.10?

Comment: no, i meant to ubuntu 14.04 when it gets released!